# ckeditor not working in IE9 and 10

Tags: java, internet-explorer-9, ckeditor, struts, internet-explorer-10

I am using the JAVA Implementation of CKEditor. So in my code I have

```
 <%@ taglib uri="http://ckeditor.com" prefix="ckeditor" %>
```

My text area uses a struts bean write tag logic

```
<textarea id="txtCmt<bean:write name="i" />:<bean:write name="j" />" name="comments" style="width: 100%; height: 280px;">
```

I then use

```
<ckeditor:replaceAll basePath="/elements/ckeditor_basic/ckeditor.js" />
```

To replace the textarea with the CKEditor. The implementation works well on Chrome and Firefox,However,the editor does not load on IE9 and the page breaks on IE10.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Any error messages? Have you checked the console?

Comment: No errors in console.

Comment: Really? Nothing in the dev console? Sounds unlikely. Can you show us a link? Do you get any 404 requests? Can you show us the rendered HTML?